# How To Access SFTP on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I inherited a linux server and I am attempting to access SFTP for a specific user.  I can access a shell with no issues using an admin account "admin" and I can also access the filesystem with Filezilla using a public rsa key.

I need to write files to a directory that is owned by user-ftp.  I reset the user-ftp password and can access everything for that user via shell with `su`, but can't seem to access `sftp` through Mozilla.  I can't find a public key for that user, but I know the previous admin was uploading files with that user.

I looked in `~/` and their is no `.ssh`.  I would appreciate any help tracking down how the current access is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a lot of things.

sftp only has two configuration options - where and what to log.  You should enable that:

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -f auth -l DEBUG
```

Restart ssh server (WARNING - easy to lock yourself out of a remote system here!)

```
service ssh restart
```

Then monitor /var/log/auth while trying to log in:

```
tail -f /var/log/auth
```

My suspicion is that your predecessor didn't use sftp, but instead rsync over ssh which can be invoked in such a way to sudo into the target account.

```
SOURCE=/path/to/local/files/
TARGET=/path/to/files/on/remote/
rsync -Pav -e "ssh" --rsync-path="sudo -u user-ftp rsync" \
   $SOURCE \
   admin@example.com:$TARGET
```

Comment: I appreciate the input and am giving you credit because you led me to the eventual answer.  I found a proftpd log (I knew it was installed, but it wasn't running, so I didn't look further into it).  It turns out he was using plain ftp (I tested it out).  I'm not sure if he was stopping the service or what.  Appreciate the help.